# ruby on rails - can I send other parameter on edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

why when I call

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_quest_path(quest), event: quest.req_event.count , prereq: prereq %>
```

the event and prereq parameter is not sent to edit page, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

please modify your code as below

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_quest_path(quest,event: quest.req_event.count , prereq: prereq) %>
```